# How to compile view in postgres

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

Is there any alternative in postgres to compile views as oracle? I searched ,but couldn't find any relevant alternatives for it . Can anyone suggest on this?

`ALTER VIEW employee COMPILE;` in oracle

Comment: why do you need to compile a view?

Comment: It's business requirement , should be followed in  postgres too as oracle

Comment: If its to validate integrity, plpgsql_check is now available but I don't know as postgres official extension and if works with view, in postgres is just the create or alter with the query

Comment: There is no compile view in postgresql. you can drop and create the view again or do an alter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL views don't have to be compiled.

This is an Oracle specific nuisance. Oracle does not make sure that the dependencies of a view remain intact, so it can happen that a view becomes invalid because one of its requisites changed or vanished.

Oracle calls such a view *invalid* and calls the process of making sure all requisites are there *compile*.

In PostgreSQL, the database management system will prevent you from changing the requisites of a view in a way that might break the view, so a view can never become invalid. Hence there is no need to check its validity.

This is convenient, but it comes at the price that you have to drop and recreate the view if you want to modify an underlying table.